# Jupyter nbconvert --to html showing Plotly graphs, but not formatted HTML text

Tags: python, html, plotly, visualization, nbconvert

I have this piece of code that outputs the following image below the piece of code when I run it in Jupyter Notebook just fine:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
pyo.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 2])],)
fig.update_layout(width = 600, height = 400, margin = dict(t = 0))
display(widgets.HBox(
    [   
        widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML("<H1>Win Rate - Spec Alpha Non-LMI </H1>"),
            go.FigureWidget(fig, layout={"width":500, "height":300}),]), 
        widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML("<H1>Win Rate - Spec Beta Non-LMI </H1>"),
            go.FigureWidget(fig, layout={"height":300}),])
    ],
))
```

[image]

However, whenever I run `jupyter nbconvert file.ipynb --to html --execute` in the Jupyter Notebook terminal, what ends up happening is that the HTML file that comes out completely messes up the titles and only shows the titles with the  tags but without the  formatting. Does anyone know why this may be occurring?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CSS styling.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
pyo.init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 2])],)
fig.update_layout(width = 600, height = 400, margin = dict(t = 0))

style = """
<style>
    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
"""

display(widgets.HBox(
    [   
        widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML(f"{style}<H1>Win Rate - Spec Alpha Non-LMI </H1>"),
            go.FigureWidget(fig, layout={"width":500, "height":300}),]), 
        widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML(f"{style}<H1>Win Rate - Spec Beta Non-LMI </H1>"),
            go.FigureWidget(fig, layout={"height":300}),])
    ],
))
```